# How to get text from hyperlink?

Tags: php

Hello i'm new in php so i want to know if there's a way to get the text from a hyperlink that has been created by a loop?
is there any solution? my problem is that i can't get the name from the hyperlink so that i will pass that name to other page .

// i have this code which doesn't work.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function GetText()
{
  var linktext=document.getElementById('testlink').innerHTML;
  <?php  $_SESSION['name'] = "<script>document.write(lintext)</script>"?> 
}
</script>
<title>Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admincss.css" />
</head>

if($pic != "")
{
$total=mysql_affected_rows();
for($ff1=0;$ff1<$total;$ff1++)
{
   print "<table width='100%' align='center' border='5'>";
   print "<td width='20%'><img src=\"$pic\" height='100px' width='100px'/>     </td>";
   print "<td align = 'center' width='20%'><a onclick='GetText()' ' href='search.report.php'  id='testlink'>$name</a></td>"; //
   print "<td align = 'center'width='20%'>$bday</td>";
   print "<td align = 'center'width='20%'>$no</td>";
   print "<td align = 'center'width='20%'>$eadd </td>";
   print "</table>";
}
 }
```

Comment: PHP and JS are different things. PHP is meant for server and JS is meant for Client side. You cannot get a JS variable to PHP unless you post it to the server.

Comment: is there a way i can get text from hyperlink using php??

Comment: Yes, you can. well, @Broken Heart has already answered. you can follow that. Its not a good approach as it can lead to XSS, but still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are talking about this line:

```
print "<td align = 'center' width='20%'><a ' href='search.report.php'  id='testlink'>$name</a></td>"; //
```

You need to write this line as below:

```
print "<td align='center' width='20%'><a href='search.report.php?name=$name' id='testlink'>$name</a></td>"; //
```

And then you can get the name on **search.report.php** file by this code:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name'];
echo $_REQUEST['name'];
```

You cann't execute the PHP code in the JS file. so you need to send it on server as PHP is server side language.

Comment: sir i have an error in your last code $_SESSION['name'] = $_REQUEST['name']. i use session to pass value to other page. i just want to get the name from the hyperlink after clicking and pass it to other page.

Comment: http://localhost/xampp/eRegform/search.report.php? name2=Victor%20Allen%20%20id= 

sir is there any way to remove this %20,%20%20id=  ?
i remove width='20%' id='testlink' . and now it is okay thank you.

Comment: @RenzCordero use the htmlentitydecode function you can read more about it from google.